# Room Migration Not Finding Table Columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room, database-migration

I wanted to drop some columns from a table in my sqlite database. I created a new table (with a different name), inserted the appropriate data from the old table into the new table. Then I dropped the old table and renamed the new table to the old table's name.
However I am getting this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: Clothes(com.dayaramo.wearyourcloset.Objects.ClothingItem).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='Clothes', columns={season=Column{name='season', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, item=Column{name='item', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, wornCount=Column{name='wornCount', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, category=Column{name='category', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, photoPath=Column{name='photoPath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='Clothes', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

My Clothing class changed to reflect the columns I removed, but I'm not sure why it can't find the columns

Clothes class

```
@Entity(tableName = "Clothes")
public class ClothingItem implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String item;
    private String season;
    private String category;
    private int wornCount;
    private String photoPath;



    public static final Creator<ClothingItem> CREATOR = new Creator<ClothingItem>() {
        @Override
        public ClothingItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ClothingItem(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ClothingItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ClothingItem[size];
        }
    };

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void setSeason(String season) {
        this.season = season;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setPhotoPath(String photoPath) {
        this.photoPath = photoPath;
    }


    public void setWornCount(int wornCount) { this.wornCount = wornCount; }

    @Ignore
    public ClothingItem(String item, String season, String category, int wornCount) {
        this.item = item;
        this.season = season;
        this.category = category;
        this.wornCount = wornCount;
    }

    public ClothingItem(String item, String season, String category, int wornCount, String photoPath) {
        this.item = item;
        this.season = season;
        this.category = category;
        this.wornCount = wornCount;
        this.photoPath = photoPath;
    }

    @Ignore
    public ClothingItem() {
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getSeason() {
        return season;
    }

    public String getPhotoPath() {
        return photoPath;
    }


    public long getId() {return id; }

    public int getWornCount() { return wornCount; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(id);
        dest.writeString(item);
        dest.writeString(season);
        dest.writeString(category);
        dest.writeInt(wornCount);
        dest.writeString(photoPath);
    }

    protected ClothingItem(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readLong();
        item = in.readString();
        season = in.readString();
        category = in.readString();
        wornCount = in.readInt();
        photoPath = in.readString();
    }
}
```

Migration code

```
@Database(entities = {ClothingItem.class, DailyOutfit.class}, version = 14)
public abstract class ClothingItemDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract ClothingDao clothingDao();
//    public abstract OutfitDao outfitDao();
    public abstract DailyOutfitDao dailyOutfitDao();

    private static volatile ClothingItemDatabase INSTANCE;
    private static final Object sLock = new Object();

....
 static final Migration MIGRATION_12_13 = new Migration(12,13) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `ClothingItems` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "`item` TEXT, `season` TEXT, `category` TEXT, `wornCount` INTEGER, `photoPath` TEXT)");

            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `ClothingItems` (`id`,`item`, `season`,`category`,`wornCount`,`photoPath`)" +
                    "SELECT `id`,`item`, `season`,`category`,`wornCount`,`photoPath` from Clothes");

        }
    };

    static final Migration MIGRATION_13_14 = new Migration(13,14) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            database.execSQL("DELETE FROM `Clothes`");
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE `Clothes`");
        }
    };


    static final Migration MIGRATION_14_15 = new Migration(14, 15) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            database.execSQL("DELETE FROM `DailyOutfits`");

        }
    };

 static final Migration MIGRATION_15_16 = new Migration(15, 16) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

//            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE `Outfits`");
        }
    };



    static  ClothingItemDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {

        if (INSTANCE == null) {

            synchronized (ClothingItemDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {

                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            ClothingItemDatabase.class, "Clothes")
                            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3, MIGRATION_3_4,MIGRATION_4_5,MIGRATION_5_6,MIGRATION_6_7
                                    ,MIGRATION_8_9,MIGRATION_9_10, MIGRATION_10_11,MIGRATION_11_12,MIGRATION_12_13,MIGRATION_13_14,MIGRATION_14_15,MIGRATION_15_16)
                            .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback).build();
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }
//    MIGRATION_7_8, MIGRATION_8_9, MIGRATION_9_10)

    private static Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
        }
    };


    /*
     * Migrate from:
     * version 1 - using the SQLiteDatabase API
     * to
     * version 2 - using Room
     * November 12,2019
     * Migrate from:
     * version 3 - using the SQLiteDatabase API
     * to
     * version 4 - using Room
     * March 19, 2020
     *to
     * version 5
     * May 3, 2020
     *to
     *version 5,6,7
     * May 3, 2020
     */


    public static ClothingItemDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        synchronized (sLock) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        ClothingItemDatabase.class, "ClothingItem.db")
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3, MIGRATION_3_4,MIGRATION_4_5,MIGRATION_5_6,
                                MIGRATION_6_7,MIGRATION_8_9,MIGRATION_9_10,MIGRATION_10_11, MIGRATION_11_12,MIGRATION_12_13,MIGRATION_13_14,MIGRATION_14_15,MIGRATION_15_16)
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build();
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I found the answer from [Lua Software Code](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-room-upgrade-database-new-table/) where I realized that I wasn't using exportSchema in my database class.

```
@Database(entities = {ClothingItem.class, DailyOutfit.class}, version = 15,exportSchema = true)
```

It creates a JSON under the assets folder every time you add a migration so you can see what's happening with the SQL commands
Once I added that and Built the project WITHOUT running it I could see how the table was being created.
Turns out that one of my columns had been changed to "Not Null" and that's what was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

**What I see from your code**:

1. It seems that current version of DB on device (before migration) is 12.
2. According to this:

```
@Database(entities = {ClothingItem.class, DailyOutfit.class}, version = 14)
```

you're attempting to change your DB version to 14.

3. Updating from 12 to 14 version will invoke two migration-methods: MIGRATION_12_13 and MIGRATION_13_14. After these methods in Sqlite there will be ClothingItems table, and table Clothes will be dropped. You've written in your post that you

> renamed the new table to the old table's name

but I can't see than in your SQL statements (There is no "ALTER TABLE" statement).

4. So after migration Sqlite know only about ClothingItems table, but you still use table's name "Clothes" in your Entity annotation:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Clothes")
public class ClothingItem implements Parcelable {
```

That I guess causes error message (expected some table but is doesn't exist).

**Propositions**:

1. To add to your migrations SQL-statement to rename your new table to old table's name ("ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO ...")

or

2. To use new table's name in your entity - "ClothingItems"

Comment: Hi Sergiy I forgot to add that part when I was adding the code. What you said pointed me into the direction I needed to find the answer